# Setting max characters to <body> with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, character, maxlength

I want to set a max characters with Jquery to a body tag. I tried the script below but that is not working. It works however on a div tag. Anyone who knows if it is even possible to set max characters to a body tag? **[Demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7pmkq04/285/)**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('body').on('keydown', function(event) {
  if($(this).text().length === 10 && event.keyCode != 8) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
});
</script>
<style>
body {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    outline: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body contenteditable="true"></body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because jsfiddle adds some stuff inside the `body` and the `.text()` picks them up and so the `.length` is not what you expect.

Try a `console.log($(this).text())` in your event handler and you will see what i mean.

Running your code on a *clean* page that does not get things injected into it, should work.